# Template for canvas html5/jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I am a beginner at HTML5, Jquery/JavaScript. 
I am attempting to create a canvas (sort of like windows paint application) and I am looking at other users sample functions/code to see whats it going on and attempt to re-create it.

```
$(function(){
var paint = new Paint($('#surface').get(0));

// Setup line template
var templateLine = new Paint($('#toolbar #line').get(0), {'readonly': true});
templateLine.shape = new Line([10, 10], [50, 50]);
templateLine.place(templateLine.shape);
```

I am unsure what is going on here. I know this new Paint is not an internal built-in function. What is it? 
Secondly whats the difference between this and

```
$( document).ready(function(){
var canvas = $("#canvas").get(0);
if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // Choose a color
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support CANVAS
    }
});
```

Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, the code you're looking at in the beginning of your question was probably using some canvas library or API, but that is *not* the vanilla HTML5 Canvas API, making it completely different from what you've written below, even if they have the same output (although it doesn't look like they do).

Secondly, `color` is not defined, so unless that's defined in your code somewhere else, your code's not going to work. Otherwise, your code will draw a black rectangle in the corner of the canvas with the stroke color of whatever `color` is.